# Ext4 secondary drive not accepted by Steam on Linux

Tags: steam, linux, hard-drive, ubuntu

My computer restarted with Steam open and upon relaunching it none of my games on a secondary internal SSD were recognized. The drive is Ext4 and the relevant line from fstab is

> UUID=99d2c67d-cbd0-43b4-af73-fad5a79fcd08 /media/datastorage ext4 defaults 0 2

All of the Steam games are still on the hard drive, but Steam says "New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions" whenever I attempt to use the app to re-add the library.

I have tried several other fstab options recommended on this platform already. My user has full read-write permissions for this folder and drive. All of my Steam library folders already have "steamapps" in all lowercase. I noticed some other users have had issues with Windows dual boot, but I do not have this and only have one Windows virtual machine set up (but not running nor on the secondary SSD).

My system information is: Pop!-OS 20.10 (Ubuntu based) on a Dell Precision 5550 with an i7-10850H and an NVIDIA Quadro T1000

Let me know if there's anything else I should include! Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the output if you run `mount`? Just show us the line that refers to this specific drive/partition (we don't need to see proc, udev, etc. outputs).

Comment: Sure thing, best I can tell, this is the line you want:  /dev/nvme0n1p1 on /media/datastorage type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the comments on [this bug from 2013](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/730), this message is triggered if Steam is unable to launch a child process by executing a script which it creates under the affected library. Here are some reasons why that might happen:

- The script lacks execute permission in its filesystem mode (the `x` flag in `ls -l`'s output). But Steam created this script, and it should have set the appropriate permissions automatically. Fix with [`chmod(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).
- Any directory in the path to the script lacks execute permission. But I would expect this to cause much more substantial problems because you would be unable to even browse your Steam library in the file explorer. You can also fix this with `chmod(1)`. *Do not pass the `-R` flag unless you are sure you know what you are doing.*
- Steam is running as a different user, which is not the normal way of setting things up, and that user lacks permissions as above. You may need to either `chmod` the library to add permissions, set up group permissions with [`groupadd(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) and [`chgrp(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chgrp.1.html), and/or use [`chown(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) to give the library (recursively if necessary) to Steam's user. Or you may simply need to make sure that Steam is running as you and not as some other user.
- The drive is mounted `noexec`, which prevents anyone from executing any binaries on the filesystem. Some Linux distributions do this automatically for removable drives, as a security measure, but I think we can rule this out based on your `mount` output. For completeness, this can be temporarily fixed with [`mount(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) but the permanent fix will depend on how your OS is mounting the drive.
- [`system(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is unable to find `/bin/sh`. But then your whole OS should be broken.
- A security tool such as SELinux or AppArmor is preventing Steam from executing binaries on this drive. These are very complicated to monkey around with.
- Some of the discussion on that bug suggests it might be a problem with case sensitivity. Try renaming the library (and in particular, the `SteamApps` subdirectory) to all lowercase.

If you try to run that script yourself (it should be named `.steam_exec_test.sh`, and may not be visible unless you show hidden files), it may provide output to help you further diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm fairly new to tinkering like this, so I'm not 100%sure what to do with the first solution, maybe you could elaborate? All of the folders leading to the steam library have full rw access as far as I am aware which rules out bullet two. I am the only user on this machine, so unless steam is launching as root or something, I'm not sure what to do with bullet three. I changed the mount option to "exec" so I don't believe bullet four should apply. Not sure about bullet five? I don't have any security tools or antivirus so I don't think six is an issue. Lastly, my steamapps is lowercase.

Comment: Character limit, starting on new line... I don't see .steam_exec_test.sh anywhere on my computer, do you know what directory it's in so that I can get more specifics? Let me know if that feedback helps. I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: @ChrisB: In traditional Unix file modes, there are *three* permissions, each of which can be granted separately to three sets of people: Read, Write, Execute, and Owner (sometimes "User"), Group, Other. Checking for read/write is completely irrelevant, because Steam is complaining about execute. If execute permissions are denied to a directory, then that prevents all access to the contents of that directory.

Comment: Ok I see. So why does steam still say that the steamlibrary directory is not executable even when I mount it with the exec option in fstab? Is there a command that I could apply to the directory to make it executable so that steam will accept it?